# AngularJS: Scope function in dynamically rendered template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here's my deal. I wrote a directive that ties to Bootstrap-UI for modals. It basically allows me to add an attribute to an element, pass some data and trigger a popup. The popup loads a template. My problem is that I want to have a close button in the template but I'm guessing that because the template is loaded on click, the scope isn't accessible to it or the popup. Here's my code.

```
.directive('modalShow', function($modal) {
    return {
        scope:{
            template: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var callback = function() {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: '/app_assets/views/popups/'+scope.template+'.html',
                    controller: function() {}
                });

            }
            scope.ok = function () {
                //Close popup function
            };
            element.bind('click', callback);
            element.addClass('pointer');
        }
    }
});
```

In my template that get's dynamically loaded in the modal I have...

```
<span ng-click="ok()">Close</span>
```

Which I'd like to close that instance of the modal.

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle?

Comment: Hm, I could try but what I have doesn't work, I'm kinda more hoping for a logistical answer telling my why it doesn't work :)

Comment: A fiddle (even if it doesn't work), will better outline the problem, and give us a better chance to figure out a solution.